# Landscaped longtable doesn't allow appendix title on same page

Tags: longtable, appendices, landscape, lscape

My landscaped longtables leave the appendix title page and are placed on the next page. Now the appendix title page is empty, apart from the one-line title. What can I do about it?

Comment: Should I maybe rephrase my question?

Comment: The `landscape` environment starts a new page. Perhaps you can move the `\section` command inside the `landscape` environment?

Comment: Is that the only way I can fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you have the suggestion to put the command `\section` inside the environment `landscape`. However the handling of the command depends on your fantasy. You can put the the command `\section` inside the environment `picture` and rotate them at the top of the page. Of course the justification can be a little bit nasty.